# Extra right margin depending on textwidth

Tags: margins, memoir

It seems that the right (outer) margin is changed from what I request, depending on textwidth. MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[letterpaper,final]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setlength\textheight{2in}
\setlength\textwidth{8.4in} % OK at 8.4, but not OK at 4.4
\setlength\foremargin{0.05in} % OK at 0.05, but not OK at 2.05
\setlength\spinemargin{0.05in} % OK at 0.05, but not OK at 2.05
\checkandfixthelayout
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\noindent O \hfill{} O\par
\end{document}
```

If I use textwidth that nearly occupies the full page, I can see that the left and right margins are identical, as expected. But if I reduce the textwidth by 4" and add 2" to each margin, then mysteriously the right (outer) margin is no longer correct. It is too large, by maybe 3 points.

The effect does not seem to depend on the font used. I do not use margin paragraphs but setting those number to zero does not help.

Apparently, there is a width-dependent factor that appears.

EDIT: I learned that memoir truncates some lengths to integer points. The discrepancy was simply due to accumulated fractional points (the amount depends on which values are used). Not really a problem.

Comment: Did you try adding `\checkandfixthelayout` after the last `\setlength` command?

Comment: Yes. I corrected the MWE. That's not the problem.

Comment: The right margin is defined as \paperwidth-1in-\oddsidemargin-\textwidth (or \evensidemargin for even pages).  Hopefully it is larger than \marginparsep+\marginparwidth.

Comment: With memoir class, using \foremargin and \spinemargin substitutes for \oddsidemargin and such, without the extra inch. But that's not the problem. In fact, it is not a problem, as I have discovered. First, the discrepancy was closer to 3 points, not 7 as I had thought. If I print out the various numbers, I learned that the numbers do not total correctly. Apparently memoir truncates some lengths down to integer points, but not others. The discrepancy was due to the fractional points accumulating. Happens more with some margins than with others. Not a big deal, since it is consistent.